# Set activity background in theme using a style?

Tags: android

I want to use a background drawable for all my activities. How can I do this with a style?

```
// styles.xml
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar.ForceOverflow">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_background</item>  
</style>
```

that sets the background for all widgets it seems. I just want it to work for activities.

Thanks

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Use

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/my_background</item>
```