# My action bar title is taking the wrong color from theme

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

I'm attempting to modify the theme for my application. I've been able to successfully set the background color for my app, and the background color for my action bar.

Unfortunately, the background color of the items WITHIN the action bar are taking the background color of the app, not the bg color of the action bar.

Here's my code from styles.xml

```
<!--
    Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
</style>


<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:background">#ff0000</item>
</style>


<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#fefefe</item>
</style>
```

and here's a screenshot of what's happening.

[image: screenshot of weird bg colors]

Hoping I'm missing something stupid here...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your theme background is being applied to *everything*. Instead, you only want the activity's background to be that color. So instead of setting the background color in the theme, you should set it for the activity. If you have many activities that will use this background color, then create a style for your activities and apply it to each one.

Comment: Thanks, this put me in the right direction...I searched on how to set the background color for an activity and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441297/set-activity-background-in-theme-using-a-style
I ended up setting the windowBackground which seems to have worked: 

     <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/red</item>

Comment: Perfect, that's even better than what I was proposing. I wasn't sure if there was an actual style property from the theme that could be applied only to the activities (and not everything else). It looks correct to me via the dev guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/your_color</item>
<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/your_color</item>
```

Worked for me.