# PreferenceActivity action bar background color

Tags: android, android-actionbar

**Dears, 
Look at the snapshot:**

[image: Settings Activity]

I use the following code to change the action bar background -same used in normal activities and works fine-:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.actionbar_background));
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_settings);

    setupSimplePreferencesScreen();
}
```

the problem is that the action bar background color changed to specified color, but the text and icon background take the activity background color.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link help me to figure the problem:

[My action bar title is taking the wrong color from theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039071/my-action-bar-title-is-taking-the-wrong-color-from-theme)

The problem was with setting Activity background color, instead of this:

```
<!-- Settings Activity -->

  <style name="SettingsTheme">
    <item name="android:Background">@color/main_menu_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/font_color</item>
  </style>
```

I use this:

```
<!-- Settings Activity -->

  <style name="SettingsTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/main_menu_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/font_color</item>
  </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.actionbar_background));
```

To:

```
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.actionbar_background)));
```

Comment: Hi, it give me this error `The method setBackgroundColor(int) is undefined for the type ActionBar`. It suggest to change it to `setBackgroundDrawable`. Any other suggestions?